# How do I execute a query using INSERT INTO and WITH statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO tablename( columnname1, columnname2, columnaname2)
WITH
a AS
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE condition
),
b AS
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE condition
)
```

I have a couple lines of query below where I use an DISTINCT statement but would like to know for now whether my query above is correct or not.

Comment: What happened when you ran it? Or did you not google 'sql online'?

Comment: The query you posted doesn't make sense. What is it that you try to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to insert whats below the with statement into a table...

Comment: Hi. What do you mean, "what's below"? Your comment is unintelligible. Also, don't clarify in comments, edit your question. Also please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

`WITH`? This is going to be introduced in MySQL 8.0. Are you using a preview release? Otherwise you won't be able to use `WITH` in MySQL.

Anyway: A `WITH` clause belongs at the beginning of the statement: `WITH ... INSERT ...`. See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html.

It seems, however, you are not even using your CTEs `a` and `b`. Your CTEs are also lacking parentheses. Your statement should look something like this for instance:

```
WITH a AS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE condition)
   , b AS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE condition)
INSERT INTO tablename(columnname1, columnname2, columnaname2)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM b;
```